# Почему выполняется условие else, если выполнилось условие if?

Tags: javascript

При вводе буквы, которое есть в переменной `word`, по идеи, если такой буквы нет, то должно выдать сообщение **Такой буквы нет**.

Но это сообщение почему-то выводится даже тогда, если эта буква есть, почему?

Если убрать последнее условие, то нормально работает:

```
var word = 'программа';    
var answerArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
  answerArray[i] = "_";
}

var remainingLetters = word.length;    
while (remainingLetters > 0 ) {    
  alert(answerArray.join(" "));    
  var guess = prompt("Угадайте букву, или нажмите Отмена для выхода из игры.");

  if (guess === null) {
    // Выходим из игрового цикла
    break;
  }           
  else {
    for (var j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {                     
      if(answerArray[j] === guess) {
        alert('Такая буква уже есть')
      }
      else if(word[j] === guess) {
        answerArray[j] = guess.toLowerCase();
        remainingLetters--;     
      }              
      else if(word[j] != guess) {
        alert('Такой буквы нету');
        break;
      }
    }   
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xqqbyexb/

Answer (score 0):

Вы выходите из цикла, используя `break;`, только тогда, когда буква, которую ввёл пользователь не равна букве, которую мы рассматриваем. Таким образом, пользователю надо угадывать буквы поочерёдно, начиная с первой.

Например,  загаданное слово у нас `абв`, а пользователь вводит букву `а`. Сначала у нас сравнятся `а` и `а`, а т.к. они равны, то первый символ в `answerArray` станет буквой `а`. Далее сравниваются `а` и `б`, а т.к. они не равны, то покажется `Такой буквы нету` и следующие буквы проверяться не будут.

А вот, собственно, исправленная версия: https://jsfiddle.net/xqqbyexb/10/. Теперь всё работает, а ещё в конце выводится загаданное слово ;)

Comment: в любой последовательности

Comment: @DivMan подправил ответ)